# Need Identical String-Hashing Implementations in Javascript, C#

Tags: c#, javascript, encryption, hash

I'd like to be able to generate a simple hash value (on an ordered set of strings, so I'm fine if it's just a hash of the concatenation of the strings) on the client side in Javascript, and generate an identical hash value on the same strings on the server side in C# for an exact comparison.  The security is not overwhelmingly critical, so I don't know if it needs to be a fullblown encryption protocol (although if that's the easiest path, I'm open to it).  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are after an identical hashing function, why not implement something well-documented, such as [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20130703081745/http://www.cogs.susx.ac.uk/courses/dats/notes/html/node114.html) in both javascript and C#, thereby guaranteeing you are hashing the same way on both the client and the server?

Comment: Thank you!  Seems nice and easy to implement on both Javascript and C# fronts.

Comment: Oops. The link is broken now.

Answer (score 0):

Murmur hash is a fast algorithm (albeit not for crypto applications).

http://code.google.com/p/smhasher/